# Как назначить IP-адреса в сети?

Tags: сеть, ip, шлюз, ip-address

Провайдер выдал для сети диапазон адресов `195.223.251.160/29`. Адрес шлюза, выданный провайдером, `195.223.251.161`. Мне нужно назначить IP-адреса следующим устройствам: компьютер, сервер, 3 IP-камеры, IP-телефон.

Я рассуждал следующим образом: исходя из маски, мне доступны адреса от `195.223.251.161` до `195.223.251.167`. При этом `195.223.251.167` - широковещательный, и его использовать нельзя, а `195.223.251.161` занят под шлюз.

Следовательно, реально я могу использовать только адреса от `195.223.251.162` и до `195.223.251.166`. То есть мне доступно всего 5 адресов, а IP-адреса нужно назначить 6 устройствам.

Верно ли я рассуждаю по поводу определения доступных IP-адресов?
Действительно ли не удастся назначить IP-адреса всем 6 устройствам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну компьютер можно и за сервер убрать, который для него маршрутизатором будет. Предлагаю просто попробовать задействовать 167 адрес, в интернете никто не будет считать его броадкастом. Разве что ваш провайдер ...

Попробуйте поставить `167` ну скажем на компьютер, если ОС начнет орать что нибудь по поводу маски и т.п. просто расширьте ее до `28`. В таком случае он не сможет увидеть реальники `195.223.251.168/29` потому как они попадут в маску и он будет считать, что они в его локалке. Но обычно это не страшно, потому как там наверняка другой клиент вашего прова, связь с которым вам не нужна. Если вдруг нужна - то это лечится прописыванием маршрутизации на эту подсеть через ваш 161 шлюз. Если выйти в интернет с него получится, то на остальные устройства то же можно поставить 28 маску, что они нормально с ним общались, не думая что он броадкаст

В большинстве случаев такие конфигурации работают нормально, хотя конечно и считаются *кривыми*

P.S. Кстати, 160 адрес то же ваш, хотя считается адресом сети, но и его то же можно попробовать использовать

Comment: Ок, поправил. Какие могут быть названия из стандартов, если я предлагаю их нарушать :)

Comment: Да, суровый подход :) Но если даже дешевого маршрутизатора с PAT-ом наперевес нет, то нужда и не до такого доведёт...

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, **да**, рассуждаете вы правильно.